# How do I pass current user session information from web application to business layer in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

How do I pass my current user-session information from the web application to the business layer in asp.net core?

---

I had tried to pass the session information from controller constructor to business logic layer object however I found the null exception for the session because the session is not initialized till the request is not completed.

Actually, in my project, I am using DI and I just want to pass session information from `UI -> BL -> DA` so that I can decide which connection string to be used in DA on the basis of user-session information also want to use current user id in my Add and Edit operation to maintain the history of the operation.

---

All DA and BL services are configured with DI and services are injected using DI.

```
   public class SystemUserController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public BL.ISystemUserService _systemUserService { get; }
        public SystemUserController(BL.ISystemUserService systemUserService, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _systemUserService = systemUserService;
            _systemUserService.Session = new RepositorySession(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.CurrentUser().SystemUserId,DatabaseConnection.CONFIG);
        }
```

Comment: How do you expect to have a session when there is no request..? The controller is initialized when the *server* is started, not when the user logs in. The session will exist once the user makes a request to a web method, you can't have a session without a request.

Comment: Actually when i try to set this _systemUserService.Session = new RepositorySession(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.CurrentUser().SystemUserId,DatabaseConnection.CONFIG); i am getting null reference exception for Session

Comment: I know you are.. the session **does not exist when the controller is initialized** 

This code is running as soon as the Controller is created, which happens when the *server starts running*

Comment: Session.CurrentUser() is a extension method to retrieve the current user from the session which I have set during the user login and authentication process

Comment: ... but the login and authentication process happens *after* this code has already run. This Controller already exists before the user logs in.

Comment: How else would the user log in if the Controllers didn't exist? Without the Controllers you don't have a website or web application, you just have some code.

Comment: That is what i am looking for alternate solution because Instance of the BL and DA services are injected through the DI so I can not create instance of the these services so is there any easy approach to share the current user infomation between the UI and BL. MVC 4 I  use HttpContext.Current.Session to retrieve session information in my BL layer now in .net core it is not possible.

Comment: Dependency injection happens at the application level typically.. you can't set up dependency injection after the user logs in, DI would happen as soon as the Controller is started up. You need to use DI to get the dependency then pass the use the dependency in a WebMethod *then* you can pass the session to the DI then to the DA

Comment: DI is configured in Startup.cs file using custom middleware so i think this get completed even before the user will login to the application                   
 //Configure Services And Repository Dependencies
            services.AddServicesAndRepositories();

Comment: That's what I've been saying.. you don't have a user, there is no session at this point. You can't pass user information to the Dependency Injection setup for a Controller, the Controller exists before the user therefore there is no user information.

Comment: Do you have any alternate way or simple suggestion to achieve this goal to pass current user information from UI -> BL -> DA

Comment: Just use a Web Method, call the Business Layer from the Web Method and send the relevant information and then have the Business Layer call the Data Access Layer using the information it gets from the Business Layer.

Comment: I feel a custom middleware sitting on the pipeline after authentication can capture the session as it's going to get created then...

Comment: UI, BL and DA all are in different project lib...

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you are trying to implement multitenancy in your application. 
One thing you can do is to write a custom middleware which extracts the tenant information from session. Then you can inject that tenant resolver in the controller. Now you have the tenant information in you controller where you can pass it to BL and DA layers.

Please read below post to get a complete understanding. 
https://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-5-multitenancy
There it considered the url to identify the user. But you can use session with the same logic instead.

This will also clear the things up for you in a detail way
https://michael-mckenna.com/multi-tenant-asp-dot-net-core-application-tenant-resolution

Comment: Yes, It is multitenant application so there is two requirement first want to extract the tenant information from the user session and second want to use current user id in ADD, EDIT and DELETE operations to maintain the history of models CRUD operation

Comment: You can create a tenant class which consists of user id and whatever properties you need to extract from the session.  From controller you can pass them down the line as I have explained above.

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot access Session values in the Business layer.

If you want to maintain a history of operations then you need to call that method in your Web project, not in BL(Business layer).